# check value of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to check a value of tensor :

```
       ytrue = y_true[0][0]
       if ytrue[index] == 1: # which to check if the label is a particular value
           do something
```

here, y_true is a tensor corresponding to a model with 4 outputs(say)
y_true[0th out put][output corresponding to 0th data point]

I face the following Value Error:
Index out of range using input dim 0; input has only 0 dims for 'loss/dense_5_loss/strided_slice_2' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[3] = <1>.